# How to change class primitive fields to respective wrapper fields dynamically for exclusion in JsonConverter to remove null fields?

Tags: java, reflection, modelmapper

I have a class from third party jar which have primitive fields inside it.
For example:

```
public class A {

private int id;

private int score;

//Getter And Setters below
}
```

I have another class which have all fields of A class and have more fields as well and can be partially updated.
For example

```
public class B {

private Integer id;

private Integer score;

private Integer age;

//Getter and Setters below
}
```

B class is in my project and can be modified. Partial update is allowed  in B class for example

```
B b = new B();
b.setAge(32);
```

Now using ModelMapper class I am doing the mapping of both the classes.

```
A object = new ModelMapper().map(b, A.class);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(object, JsonNode.class);
```

As A class have primitive data type fields hence after mapping those fields get initialized with default value.

| Current Outcome | Expected Outcome |
| --- | --- |
| {"id" : 0, "score" : 0 ,"age" 32} | {"age": 32} |

Is there a way using which we can convert the A class primitive data types to wrapper classes like int to Integer so that instead of default value it get initialized with NULL value and later on can be ignore in JSON converter?

Or is there any way using which we can achieve this using ModelMapper.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert the A class primitive data types to wrapper classes"? Do you want to change the types in the `class A` declaration? Or do you want to assign the values in `class A` to another variable? The first one is difficult if not impossible. The second one is trivial.

Comment: Hi @Code-Apprentice, I dont want to change the variable names. I want to have them as "null" instead of their default values which I think can be possible if we can change the data type to wrapper classes like int to Integer.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You can't treat some primitives as primitives and some as their wrapper classes.

Comment: Can we clone this A class to some other class changing its field through reflection instead of manually? Is it possible?

Comment: @NaveenKumar You could create a class B like you show and just assign values. No need to make it complicated with reflection.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, But what about maintainability like if in future there is any new field added in A class then same we have to handle in B class like we have to keep track on A class every time for any field update. Thoughts?

Comment: That’s obviously an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Just solve the *actual task* in a different way, without the requirement to create `B` out of `A`. If you have a question about a JSON converter, you should ask a question about that JSON converter.